# Replacing pneumatic bicycle tires with Honeycomb Hole non-pneumatic tires

Tags: tire

Can I replace my 24×1.95" pneumatic bicycle tires that came stock on my Yukon Trail Navigator SF24 ebike with 24×1 3/8" Honeycomb Hole type solid non-pneumatic bicycle tires?

Comment: Hello Tim Carnahan. Welcome to Stack Exchange.
Most people find it rather hard to read text written in capital letter. Would you be so kind to click on the 'edit' link right below your question and format it such that it is more readable. This safes volunteers (users or mods) the time to do that. Have a look at the [tour] to learn more on how SE works.

Comment: You may find useful information to your question at Sheldon Browns webpage: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Comment: Tire size numbers are weird.  A 28 inch tire fits on a smaller rim than a 27 inch tire.  And tires with fractional widths (eg 1-3/8) tend to have different rim diameters depending on the specific fraction.  The Sheldon Brown web page referenced above gives the gory details.

Comment: Hi Tim - what's your end-goal here?  To get rid of the air-filled tyre and replace with a solid tyre ?

Answer (score 7):

Most likely the 24" 1 3/8" tyres will not fit on you bike with 24" x 1.95" tyres. While the inch diametre is the same, decimal and fractional number usually mean different standards for tyre sizing.

[Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) provides tables with sizes. Here is an excerpt:

```
24 x 1.5-24 x 2.125 | 507 mm        | Juvenile mountain bikes, cruisers

24 x 1 3/8          | (E-5) 540 mm  | British Juvenile, most wheelchairs; 
                                      common on women's utility bicycles in Japan.
```

Please check if your tyres provide also an ETRTO number, such as 50-540. ETRTO numbers give the nominal tyre width followed by bead circle diametre, also in milimetres.

If the larger number matches, the tyre is intended for a rim of the same size.

At that point you have to check if rim and tyre width are compatible and if the tyre clears the frame and brakes. Both are usually not an issue when the sizes are about the same. Unless you have very little tyre clearance with your present tyres already.